# How to add data to string in a message.channel.send?

Tags: javascript, discord

My code is the following:

```
client.on('message',message => {
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ + /);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


for (let i = 0; i < array1.length;i++) { 
    
    if (command === array[i]) {
        message.channel.send( { embeds: ['https://www.google.com/search?q' &&array1[i]]});
    }

}
```

Whenever I write with the prefix in discord (or any message), I get the following error:
(node:8604) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: What is `client`? What is the type of `message`? Can you link its documentation please so that we know what you're dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

"message" event was for v12 of discord.js.

On v13 you should use "messageCreate" instead of "message" on your event.

Here is code example;

```js
client.on('messageCreate',message => {
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ + /);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


for (let i = 0; i < array1.length;i++) { 
    
    if (command === array[i]) {
        message.channel.send( { embeds: ['https://www.google.com/search?q' &&array1[i]]});
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it has solved some other problems I had. Although the bot do not answer when I send !cow and Cow is in my array..